# Golang template stop rendering

Tags: templates, go

im rendering a response.

in my code I passed a Slice with structs to display some info

in one place i use a select and the options are rendered with a range method

```
package main

import ("fmt"
"html/template"
"os"
)

func main() { 

    lista:=[3]string{"one","two","tree"}

    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    a:=`<script type="text/text">{{range .}} <option></option>hi{{end}}</script> \n  <script     type="text/text">{{range .}} <option>hi!{{end}}</script> <script type="text/text">{{range .}} <option>hi!{{end}}</script> <script type="text/text">{{range .}} <option>hi!{{end}}</script>`
    tmp,_:=template.New("tmp").Parse(a)
    tmp.Execute(os.Stdout,lista)
```

}

EDIT

I replicated the issue
http://play.golang.org/p/d62J3TOc1N
if you add the  or any other closure tag (starting with /) the render won't happened

Comment: Can you show us the rendering code and, if possible, code on play.golang.com to reproduce this?

Comment: im doing it. but i noticed other thing. any tag closed inside the range <option> </option> or <p></p> will make the template to stop rendering

Comment: culnt replicate in the playground :(

Comment: Still no rendering code, can't help you without the code.

Comment: this template is wrapped inside a <script type="text"></script> to pass it to the html page and not rendering it. outside of this tags the range works flawlessly . i had done this in the same template but looks like the template system don't like doing this :(

Comment: Show whole code and whole template which fails. Please stripped to a bare minimum showing the problem.

Comment: sorry to bother you. i moved my code template from inside the <script> tag which stored it and but it inside a hidden plaintext instead and it worked again. the only way to replicate the error was with multiple range methods and templates inside a <script> tag

Comment: @Freaktor Again, we need the go code and the template. Until now we only have the template. Deliver the go code and we might be able to help.

Comment: @nemo: added a google playground example

Comment: also looks like its only happened in "html/template", in the package "text/template" works flawlessly, looks like the html version got some intelligence and it got broken when is use multiple ranges inside a tag and with mixed html tags

Comment: @nemo erm. added the working example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace "html/template" with "text/template"
Do you get the expected result?

Comment: yep. it worked. but i want to know why html/template has this issue. :(

Comment: I tried some codes.This occurs when CLOSE TAGs exist in SCRIPT TAG.And when I double-quoted CLOSE TAG, it was rendered. I guess "html/template" always handle SCRIPT TAG as <script type="text/javascript">.